# Indirect Alternative Function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to get/reference/link cell K9 from numerous excel files and list then in a row.

The files are all in the same folder and I have the file names listed dynamically (using Name Function:Files) next to each one I need to put value of cell K9. The list will change as new files are added.

Files are closed so no good with indirect.

I can’t work out a formula to work unless I used indirect and open every file. Which isn’t practical.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Well with formulas this *"I used indirect and open every file"* would be the only way. Otherwise you need to write a VBA code that opens all files to pull the value of each file.

Comment: Ok. Any ideas on a code ?

Comment: Because this is no free code writing service, you must do some research and try it on your own first. There are so many tutorials here on Stack Overflow that explain how to loop through files in a folder, and Google has even more. Give it a try on your own and if you get stuck or errors come back with a concrete question to the code you have written so far. Otherwise this would just asking us to do all the work for you.